# AS3 & XML - How do I construct xml data in as3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am playing around with saving .xml files from data in my game. I know how to convert an xml object to a `ByteArray` and write that to a `FileReference`. What I need to know now is how to go from an empty xml object (using `var xml:XML = new XML()`) to a fully populated xml object.

Can someone show me what functions to use to add nodes and values? Specifically I need to know how to make several of the same type of node. Here's a sample of what the final xml should look like:

```
<data>
    <player>
        <money>15831</money>
        <shipType>1</shipType>
        <ship>
            <fuelCur>450</fuelCur>
            <energyCur>160</energyCur>
            <shieldCur>100</shieldCur>
            <armorCur>40</armorCur>
            <structCur>15</structCur>
        </ship>
    </player>
    <currentSystem>3</currentSystem>
    <currentPlanet>3</currentPlanet>
    <date>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>10</month>
        <day>15</day>
    </date>
    <missionFlag>true</missionFlag>
    <planet id="0">
            <population>0</population>
    </planet>
    <planet id="1">
            <population>29827632</population>
    </planet>
    <planet id="2">
            <population>0</population>
    </planet>
</data>
```

It might be useful to know how to remove and how to alter nodes and values, too.

Also, do I need to import something from the flash library to do this with XML? I'm using FlashDevelop, but when I type `xml.`, FlashDevelop doesn't bring up suggestions like it normally does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Editing XML in AS3 is actually pretty easy and pretty basic - it's a core part of AS3. AS3 automatically adds nodes as you call them, like so:

```
var xml:XML = <data />;
xml.player.money = 15831;
xml.player.shiptype = 1;
xml.player.ship.fuelCur = 450;
```

Will result in:

```
<data>
    <player>
        <money>15831</money>
        <shiptype>1</shiptype>
        <ship>
            <fuelCur>450</fuelCur>
        </ship>
    </player>
</data>
```

Then to add multiples of the same node, just start a new XML object of the type you want, and append it to the XML object you're working on. Or skip the separate xml object entirely. Repeat as many times as needed:

```
var segment:XML = <planet />;
xml.appendChild(segment); // xml.planet[0]
xml.appendChild(segment); // xml.planet[1]
xml.appendChild(<planet />); // xml.planet[2]
//etc...
```

Then you can add values to them by their indexes.

```
//Assuming this is the 4th planet you've added...
xml.planet[3].population = 29827632;
```

Comment: ha, all this time i've just been using `appendChild()` - i didn't know you could attach new nodes using dot syntax :D

Comment: There are not only plenty of tutorials, but if I type 'as3' in the Google search box, the 4th item in the drop-down is 'as3 xml'.  Here are a few example tutorials: [ex1](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/), [ex2](http://willperone.net/Code/as3xml.php), [ex4](http://www.thetechlabs.com/xml/create-a-as3-slideshow-with-xml/), [ex4](http://delfeld.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/xml-quick-reference/)

Comment: @wvxvw - Mentioning that XML is a core data type in AS3 did more to help my understanding than the other comments on this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In FlashDevelop, try creating a separate XML file entirely.  That will give you better code prompting.

For XML, though, I have found that Adobe's rudimentary [docs on their XML class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) has a wealth of useful examples and tools for creating and using XML objects.

Comment: How would I make a separate xml file? And how would that help with code prompting?

Comment: I hate to not answer a question, but this is really basic FlashDevelop and AS3 info.  I think the best answers would be found by Googling "as3 load xml tutorial" and "FlashDevelop create new XML file".

Comment: I've googled around, and haven't found any particularly clear tutorials. http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/create_edit_xml.htm was one I found that seemed like what I needed, but several of the functions aren't even in the XML model from what I can tell.

Comment: His code seems ok.  I am not being critical when I say this, but I think you need to find some intro tutorials to AS3 implementation of XML, and actually build some programs from them.  If you are new to AS3, then start with the "Hello, World!" kind of stuff, and move on up.

Comment: @iND i actually think he's trying to create XML from within flash, rather than separately (useful for example, if you're making a level editor)

Comment: @divillysausages, he was asking about code prompting within FlashDevelop as well.  Thus the external file comments.  FlashDevelop does better prompting using a file with the *.xml extension.  As far as creating XML, there are many (hundreds?) of well documented examples; he is willing to read, so my assumption was/is that he does not understand OOP very well, which is critical to understanding AS3.  I could give (redundant) examples here, but that will not solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed trying to make xml from within Flash to save to file, not a separate file to load into Flash. As for documented examples, I had trouble finding ones that told me what I needed to know, which is WHY I asked here in the first place. Most of the examples I found explained how to import XML into flash, which I've done numerous times. As for the example I linked to on kirupa.com, the two functions the author mentions that I'd need most - `XMLobj.createElement("node name")` and `XMLobj.createTextNode("text value")` - don't exist.

Comment: My apologies if I offended you.  But it just seems that the XML docs would have provided plenty of answers.  For example, the reference to `appendChild` [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#appendChild%28%29) has this example, which seems exactly what you need: `var xml:XML = 
        <body>
            <p>hello</p>
        </body>;
        
xml.appendChild(<p>world</p>);    
trace(xml.p[0].toXMLString()); // <p>hello</p>
trace(xml.p[1].toXMLString()); // <p>world</p>`